# how to remove duplicates from two different 2d arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a two 2D arrays which I'm trying to compare and remove the duplicates from one of them. I know how to removed duplicates from 1D arrays, but I have never tried with two 2D arrays, I was hoping anyone know a method to get this done. With 1D arrays I would've done `var newArray = array1.Except(array2);`  but 2d arrays don't seem to work the same way :( This is the data type I'm working with:

[image]

[image]

The fields are Text and date for both, my main goal is to be able to remove from "elMultiArray" the ones that match with "fMultiArray"

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplished:

```
string[,] array1 = { { "123", "09/17/17" }, { "456", "09/17/17" }, { "789", "09/18/17" } };
string[,] array2 = { { "147", "09/17/17" }, { "789", "09/20/17" }, { "123", "09/19/17" } };
//Output: string[,] array 3 = {456, 09/17/17}
```

Would anyone be so kind to give me at least a direction on this? Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Related: you might try out [this VS extension for visualizing arrays](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmirLiberman.ArrayVisualizer).

Comment: @Amy, I didn't know about that but looks mighty useful. Thanks!

Comment: Are the 2 arrays of the same dimension? When you say duplicates, *do you mean the same values in the same coordinates*? What should the final output look like?

Comment: Use the overload to define how items should be compared: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you consider a "duplicate"? It would be helpful if you provided a small sample code that creates two arrays, with some duplicate data, and then specify which data you'd want to remove. At first glance, I suspecte a `Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>` might be a better container than a `string[,]`.

Comment: @code4life the two arrays have different dimensions, they both have 2 columns but one has 146 rows and the second one has 251 rows. let me explain better what is going on: the fMultiArray are entries operators have been manually entered, the elMultiArray is all the entries they should've done. I want my output to be a 2d array with just the entries the operators didn't recorded, I thought maybe comparing the array elMultiArray and fMultiArray and removing the duplicates between those two would be the best approach, hope that clear some of the confusion, Thanks :)

Comment: @RufusL I'll try that out, I agree with you that the way I'm containing this data is not the best, but giving the circumstances that was the only option I had, I will give a try to your recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: @Amy Thanks a lot for that link, I didn't know VS had that feature!

Comment: @RufusL Please see edited Question :) I added some code to be easier to understand

Comment: Similar to what @RufusL has said - if you can't compare by coordinates, then you must compare by value, so transforming the 2D array into a flatter list would be ideal. However, rather than using a `Dictionary`, I think that using a `HashSet<Tuple<string, DateTime>>` might make your life easier. That way, you just keep adding tuples to the hashset, and let the .NET tuple/hashset implementation take care of the sorting and duplication handling. Once the hashset is fully loaded, just unload it back, into a 2D array.

Comment: @DennisKuypers I try your answer but I get an error Showing: "Cannot Create an Instance of the abstract class or interface "StringComparer" Here is what I did:                                                                                                                 'IEnumerable<string> except = elMultiArray.Except(fMultiArray, new StringComparer());'

Comment: @code4life can I transform a 2d Array to a list and still keep the values (string, date) Correlating??

Comment: @dreamheart: you'd have to retain the (string, date) into an object. My proposal was to use the `Tuple`, as a cheap way to go about this without having to ceremoniously define a new class.

Comment: @code4life I'm sorry, but would you be able to show me some example? I have never really deal with `Tuple` Sorry to ask!

Comment: Is it considered a duplicate if only one dimension matches? Or do both dimensions need to match?

Comment: @SamAxe the First Dimension is their order number, second is the date when it was entered, I only care for duplicates on the order number, but if it is duplicated then I have to remove the order number and the date that goes with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2-D arrays are really poor data structures, given the vastly improved data structures available in the .NET framework.  However, you indicated that you had to use them for some reason, so here goes.

Normally we'd do this in a single LINQ statement.  But LINQ does not have 2D array methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string[,] array1 = { { "123", "09/17/17" }, { "456", "09/17/17" }, { "789", "09/18/17" } };
            string[,] array2 = { { "147", "09/17/17" }, { "789", "09/20/17" }, { "123", "09/19/17" } };
            //Output: string[,] array 3 = {456, 09/17/17}

            List<string> keys = new List<string>();
            Dictionary<string, string> output = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // grab the first-dimension values
            for(int index =0; index < array2.GetLength(0);index++) {
                keys.Add( array2[index, 0]);
            }

            // compare they first-dimension values that we extracted to the first-dimension values in the 
            // source array.  If no match is found, then it is not a duplicate entry, so record it in
            // the output container.
            for (int index = 0; index < array1.GetLength(0); index++) {
                if (!keys.Contains(array1[index,0])) {
                    output.Add(array1[index, 0], array1[index, 1]);
                }
            }

            // transforming the output Dictionary<> into a 2D array is left as an excersize for the reader.

            // print output
            foreach(var key in output.Keys) {
                Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {output[key]}");
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Sam Axe, I encounter some problems but I soon realize that I also had some duplicates within one of the arrays, after removing those your answer worked perfectly fine! Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score -1):

2D arrays are not supported by linq, but you can write an `Except2D()` that is iterable and yields `Tuple<string, string>`.
You can use a `HashSet<string>` to store duplicate keys. The `Add` function can be used to check if the key is already existent.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[,] array1 = { { "123", "09/17/17" }, { "456", "09/17/17" }, { "789", "09/18/17" } };
    string[,] array2 = { { "147", "09/17/17" }, { "789", "09/20/17" }, { "123", "09/19/17" } };

    // .ToArray() not required when only iterating once
    // and .Length is not required
    var elements = array1.Except2D(array2).ToArray();

    // make it a 2D array, if required
    string[,] combined = new string[elements.Length, 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
    {
        combined[i, 0] = elements[i].Item1;
        combined[i, 1] = elements[i].Item2;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> Except2D(this string[,] a, string[,] b)
{
    HashSet<string> keys = new HashSet<string>();
    for (int index = 0; index < a.GetLength(0); index++)
    {
        if(keys.Add(a[index, 0]))
        {
            yield return new Tuple<string, string>(a[index, 0], a[index, 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my other concern, having duplicates keys, I found a way to work around it but your method is a lot better. Thanks :)